# Deploy a project with Theo into Vapor cloud v2

Tags: neo4j, vapor, vapor-cloud

I'm starting to use Vapor (the server-side Swift framework) and I saw the driver named Theo made for Vapor. But I am wondering how I would  deploy a project with Theo into Vapor Cloud 2? Does Vapor Cloud 2 support it?

**Update:**
Here's the link for Theo 5.0 from Neo4j: https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift

Comment: Any particular link for "… driver named Theo _made for Vapor._"? Appears that [Theo is a Swift interface for Neo4j](https://github.com/Neo4j-Swift/Neo4j-Swift) … and that [Neo4j is written in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j) … thus a pivotal underlaying question might be if a Java-based resource can be deployed on Vapor Cloud v2?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following facts:

1. Theo supports Linux (from the GitHub description)
2. Vapor Cloud 2 can host basically anything that has a Docker file.

You should be just fine hosting your project on Vapor Cloud 2.

As for how you would host it, you would do that the same way you would host any other app from what I can tell.